# Java scripts linking in ASP .NET application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, bundle

I have some problem with my custom async-navigation.js file: it does not see jquery and ajax scripts that are referenced.
My async-navigation.js is located in ../Scripts/custom folder. My jquery scripts are located in ../Scripts/jQuery folder and ajax scripts is located in ../Scripts/ajax. I alыo have BundleConfig.cs file wich has following content:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/custom/async-navigation.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jQuery/*.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ajax").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/ajax/*.js"));
```

I use all the bundles in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<body>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("exit", "Logout", "Login")
</div>

<div>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ajax")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")
</div>
```

The problem is there are some calls to ajax and jquery libraries in my async-navigation.js like $.ajax, .html etc. I simply can not navigate to these methods by clicking F12 and of course it doesn't work at all. What is the problem?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console/?

Comment: Are you attempting to "Go To Definition" for @Scripts.Render ? ... If you are ,then it will not show you the method definition or javascript file associated with that call... Sorry if i miss understood the question

Comment: I just try to press F12 inside my async-navigation.js in the $.ajax() method. Actually I started with Empty ASP .NET project and add all the scripts manually. When I create nonempty project with predefined jquery scripts, everything works fine. I think I miss something in bundles configuration or in web.config file...

Comment: Console says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    http://localhost:52097/bundles/jquery

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to add BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles) in my Global.asax. It works now